# Symfony 3.4 Collection Embedding With Default Value

Tags: symfony, collections, symfony-forms

I have an issue with passing the default value to a form. It just doesn't appear in the form.
I've tried to follow the official documentation, and seems to be configured correctly.

The **$facets_landing_page** is a doctrine entity from ->find($id) with a one to many relationship. facetsLandingPage is the name of the collection (containing many) inside the $facets_landing_page object.

If I pass $facets_landing_page as a **'data'** option directly into the **->add** function, it shows in the form but then has issues on save submit.

*Form creation:*

```
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($facets_landing_page)
  ->add('facetsLandingPage', FacetsLandingPageType::class);
```

Then `$form->createView()` etc.

*The custom type:*

```
class FacetsLandingPageType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add(
            'facetsLandingPage', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => FacetsLandingPageDescriptionType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                ],
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'label' => false,
            ]
        );
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'flpwrapper';
    }
}
```

*The child type:*

```
class FacetsLandingPageDescriptionType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('language', LanguageSelectType::class);
        $builder->add('fec', FecSelectType::class, ['required' => false]);
        $builder->add('title', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('meta_title', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('meta_description', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('markdown', MarkdownType::class);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'flp';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => FacetsLandingPageDescription::class,
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'collection_item',
                ],
            ]
        );
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {
        $view->vars['tab_title'] = 'New';
        if (!empty($form->getData())) {
            $view->vars['tab_title'] = $form->getData()->getTabTitle();
        }

        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like `FacetsLandingPageType` wasn't getting any default value from the form. So I got rid of it, and I passed the item directly into the main form

```
->add(
            'facetsLandingPage', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => FacetsLandingPageDescriptionType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                ],
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ]
        )
```

Comment: I wondered why you needed an intermediary form if this was the only usage, you are better off this way I guess !

Comment: @FlorentDestremau I guess it wasn't actually necessary.
I don't know symfony that well yet.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `prototype_data` attribute in your collection declaration. You can adapt something like the following.

```
        ->add(
            'collectionItems',
            CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type'    => CollectionItemType::class,
                'prototype_data' => new CollectionItemType()
            ]
        )
```

Comment: Oh sorry, it was a Collection already. I copied the wrong version of the code. It's already a collection type with the FacetsLandingPageDescriptionType entry type